Mac Safari Class not affect on the DOM
Please check below my code first
<div
  [ngClass]="{'no-height': noTemplateFound}"
  class="masonry-container-wrap w-100 d-block grid"
  id="search-grid"
  appPinGrid
  [columns]="5"
  [gutter]="25"
  [data]="templateList"
  [itemClass]="'search-item'"
  [minColWidth]="150"
  [maxColWidth]="230"
  [doubleColumnWidth]="465"
  (onLayoutComplete)="layoutComplete()"
>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!dialogData.type">
    <div
      class="custom-design cust-temp-item-new gradient-loader-light"
      id="{{'masonry-item-'+i}}"
      *ngFor="let template_details of templateList;let i = index;"
      [style.background-color]="template_details.color_value"
      [style.opacity]="0"
    >
      <div class="search-item-grid">
        <a rel="nofollow">
          <img
            class="iso-grid-item img-fluid search-item m-0"
            [src]="template_details.thumbnail_image"
            (load)="removeLoader($event)"
            *ngIf="(template_details.is_free==0 || template_details.is_free==1) && login_response.user_detail.role_id != 1"
            (click)="template_details.is_free == 0 && (login_response.user_detail.subscr_expiration_time && utils.compareDateWithCurrentDate(login_response.user_detail.subscr_expiration_time) != -1 && login_response.user_detail.role_id != 1)?showPaymentDialog(template_details):chooseTemplate(template_details)"
        /></a>
      </div></div
  ></ng-container>
</div>


I have implement this type of to custome directive to load data but issue is when i scroll down the then api calling and directive called and its all working but that that component not affect on the dom only that class style show in insepect but not bind that class on the dom this isss only in Mac Safari
This is my API Calling logic
.then(async (results: any) => {
  this.isApiInProcess = false;
    if (results.data.content_list && results.data.content_list.length > 0 && payLoad.catalog_id == this.catalog_id) {
      console.log("Yeeep This Block Called......");
      // for masonry layout
      await results.data.content_list.forEach(element => {
          that.templateList.push(element);
      });
      this.isNextPage = results.data.is_next_page;
      this.appendItem(results.data.content_list, payLoad.catalog_id);
      await this.detectChangeInArray(this.templateList)
      this.noTemplateFound = false;
  }
}


Your question as-is is difficult to parse. Please consider reformatting its contents with appropriate code blocks to improve readability.
